# I want to remove product description in featured module in the home page opencart2.0.0.0

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I want to remove Featured, latest, Latest by category, specials product Description on home page of opencart 2.0.0.0. I just want to display only Product Image, price, Add to cart, wish list, compare. Please help me to this problem. how do i solve it.

Answer (score 5):

Remove or comment the line:

`<p><?php echo $product['description']; ?></p>`

in the following files

- `catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/special.tpl`
- `catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/featured.tpl`
- `catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/latest.tpl`

Comment: Your answer has totally nothing to do with OP's question. He wants to remove the description text from those modules, and not the actual modules.

Comment: That's more like it. I've changed my downvote to an upvote.